# AudioContext create circular buffer

Tags: javascript, html, audio

It seems that to play audio data using HTML `AudioContext` you must put audio data into a `AudioBuffer` via `audioContext.createBufferSource`. The limitation here seems to be that you cannot continually add to this buffer source. How then can one create a circular buffer that you can keep appending audio data to so that I don't have to play tiny clips over and over? If I keep playing 1 second sound clips for example, to reconstruct some streaming audio, I get a click/pop between each sound, and this is bad.